# Sort ArrayList with hashmap with int values

Tags: android

I have an arraylist which contains hashmaps with several key/value pairs. One of the key/value pairs contains the key "Order" and the value is an int. How can I sort the arraylist according the "Order" key of the hashmaps it contains please? (I can do it for a string value but not an int value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would do it:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String, Integer>>() {

  final static String COMPARE_KEY = "Order";

  @Override
  public int compare(Map<String, Integer> lhs, Map<String, Integer> rhs) {
    Integer v1 = lhs.get(COMPARE_KEY);
    Integer v2 = rhs.get(COMPARE_KEY);
    return v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is keep the `HashMap` as an attribute of some custom class and create the `List` as `List<CustomClass>` . You can then let your `CustomClass` implement `Comparable` or have a `Comparator` for this custom sort . It will be easier to sort in this case.

Or define a `Comparator` which compares two `Map` objects and use it in `Collections.sort()`.

```
public class MyCustomComparator implements Comparator<Map <String, Integer>> 
{
   @Override
   public int compare (Map<String, Integer> o1, Map<String, Integer> o2) 
   {
    return o1.get("Order").compareTo(o2.get("Order"));       
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a custom Comparator such as this :

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, ?>> {
    public compare(HashMap<String, ?> o1, HashMap<String, ?> o2) {
        return o1.get("Order").toString().compareTo(o2.get("Order").toString());
    }
}
```

you then sort your list using :

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator());
```